# How to create a DataFrame from a dictionary which contains DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, weather-api

I have a dictionary which contains a dataframe for each key. The dictionary comes from this code:

```
for city in a:
        forecast = api.get_forecast(city='city')
        b = pd.DataFrame(forecast.get_series(['temp','precip','clouds','weather']))
        for lab,row in b.iterrows():
            b.loc[lab,"Forecast"]=b.iloc[lab][4]['description']
        b= b.drop(['weather'],axis=1)
        d[city]=b
```

So that I have for each city the weather features for several time units. I would like to make a new dataframe containing all the keywords with an additional column for each key for all the keywords inside it. This step is necessary because I need to upload it to amazon redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with a list comprehenation to combine your dictionary values, and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add a column giving the city:

```
df = pd.concat([v.assign(city=k) for k, v in d.items()], ignore_index=True)
```